# How to return dynamic values in Dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a query where I am returning dynamic data and am unable to retrieve the values through Dapper as listed in their documentation (https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

They have a sample of code like this:

```
var rows = connection.Query("select 1 A, 2 B union all select 3, 4");

Assert.Equal(1, (int)rows[0].A);
```

Yet, when I do the following, I cannot access any of the members of the result of my query:

```
var query = db.Query("SELECT SUM(UserRating) as 'Sum', AVG(UserRating) as 'Average', COUNT(*) as 'Total' FROM ActivityLogs");

query.FirstOrDefault(); // {{DapperRow, Sum= '3', Average = '3', Total = '1'}}
var sum = query[0].Sum; // error!
```

Error message:

> Error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

How do I get to my fields?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to do something like this. You need to add the return type of the query to **dynamic** and then cast each row into an `IDictionary<string, object>`. Once you do that, you'll be able to get the value for your query by key like so:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> query = db.Query<dynamic>("SELECT SUM(UserRating) as 'Sum', AVG(UserRating) as 'Average', COUNT(*) as 'Total' FROM ActivityLogs");
foreach (var rows in query)
{
    var fields = rows as IDictionary<string, object>;
    var sum = fields["Sum"];
    // ...
}
```

I hope it helps others!

Answer (score 4):

If you are using C# 7 or higher, you can also use [value tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) to map the returned rows. This avoids usage of `dynamic`, and has better type safety.

The query in question may then look like this (line breaks added to prevent scrolling):

```
var query = db.Query<(int Sum, int Average, int Total)>(@"
     SELECT SUM(UserRating) as 'Sum',
            AVG(UserRating) as 'Average',
            COUNT(*) as 'Total'
     FROM ActivityLogs");

var firstSum = query.FirstOrDefault().Sum;
```